# Handing Special characters in Jstree

Tags: jstree

I am building Jstree in my web application. I am passing XML as data to JStree. This XML data is built in server side(servlet) and populated into Jstree through AJAX call. When XML response have some Special/reserved Characteres like **&**, **'**(single quote) the tree is not getting built. Can any one suggest to fix this issue and how to escape then in Jstree?...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape some characters when using xml. `&` is one of them.

`An ampersand (&) may be escaped numerically (&#38;) or with a general entity (&amp;)`